# SQL Server 2005 stored procedure problem

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am writing a stored procedure like this:

```
create PROC uspInvCustomerLineItemGetList1(@CustomerID varchar(50))
AS
BEGIN   
    SELECT LineItemID, LineItemName 
    from tblInvoiceLineItems
    where CustomerID = @CustomerID 
       or CustomerID = '' 
       and AccountNumber = (select AccountNumber from tblInvAccountDetails 
                            where AccountTypeID = 10 and 20)

END
```

My problem is sub query passing 2 or more values `(select AccountNumber from tblInvAccountDetails where AccountTypeID = 10 and 20)` so I will compare both `accountnumbers (1000, 10003, 1006)` based on `AccountTypeID = 10 and 20`

How can I write the stored procedure please?

Thank You

hemanth

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note the FAQs: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/27535

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `IN` not `=`

```
...
where
    CustomerID=@CustomerID
    or
    CustomerID=''
    and
    AccountNumber IN  (select AccountNumber from tblInvAccountDetails where AccountTypeID IN (10, 20))
```

Note:

- AccountTypeID can not be both 10 and 20 at the same time: I assume you mean OR. IN is a shorthand for multiple ORs
- AND has precedence over OR so check if you need `(` and `)` somewhere